# esbuild build does not bundle the public directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules, esbuild

I decided to use `esbuild` to bundle my express API. So far all is good, except that the `public` directory which holds the `swagger` UI is not being bundled with the rest of the application.
I have an endpoint defined as a static route which serves that folder.

```
app.use(express.static(`${root}/public`));
```

To overcome this problem I have tried multiple things, such as manually copying the `public directory` to the `build dir` location. That did not seem to work.
I have also tried with the plugin `esbuild-plugin-public-directory`, which did not work either.

Then I added the `public/index.html` to the `entryPoints` configuration, which did not work either.

My question now is, what am I doing wrong? I don't seem to find anything particularly useful over the internet to help me overcome this problem.

This is the esbuild config which I am currently using.

```
const publicDir = require("esbuild-plugin-public-directory");

const OUTDIR = "build";

const envPlugin = {
    name: "env",
    setup(build) {
        // Intercept import paths called "env" so esbuild doesn't attempt
        // to map them to a file system location. Tag them with the "env-ns"
        // namespace to reserve them for this plugin.
        build.onResolve({ filter: /^env$/ }, (args) => ({
            path: args.path,
            namespace: "env-ns",
        }));

        // Load paths tagged with the "env-ns" namespace and behave as if
        // they point to a JSON file containing the environment variables.
        build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/, namespace: "env-ns" }, () => ({
            contents: JSON.stringify(process.env),
            loader: "json",
        }));
    },
};

require("esbuild")
    .build({
        entryPoints: ["server/start.ts", "public/index.html"],
        platform: "node",
        bundle: true,
        minify: false,
        platform: "node",
        logLevel: "info",
        sourcemap: false,
        target: "node12",
        loader: {
            '.html': 'text',
        },
        outdir: "build",
        plugins: [envPlugin, publicDir()],
    })
    .then(() => {
        fs.copyFileSync("server/common/api.yml", `${OUTDIR}/api.yml`);
        console.log(`Successfully built, output directed to the ${OUTDIR} directory`);
    })
    .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

Comment: I found an unholy solution where I add all `.html` files to the entryPoints array which seems to get the job done.

Comment: The solution above still relies on the `public` directory which sits on the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out if using @fastify/swagger. Just put @fastify/swagger in esbuild build.external

```
buid({external: ["esnext", "@fastify/swagger"],})
```

Otherwise maybe put swagger-ui-dist. Reference: https://docs.devland.is/repository/openapi#configuring-swaggerui-dependencies-for-esbuild

Answer (score 0):

Just add both @fastify/swagger and @fastify/swagger-ui to external:

```
const esbuild = require("esbuild");

esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ["src/app.ts"],
  platform: "node",
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  outfile: "built/index.js",
  external: ["@fastify/swagger", "@fastify/swagger-ui"],
});
```